# Does Google index ajax data that load after 1 second by setTimeout?

Tags: googlebot, search-engine-indexing, google-index, ajax, crawlable-ajax

I use load Javascrpt and use Ajax for load content.
And i should use setTimeout for run Ajax load function after 1 or 2 second(s).
Does Google index and follow this content?

Comment: You can test it using [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) and [Fetch as Bingbot](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/fetch-as-bingbot-fe18fa0d) to view the site as they do.